# Case insensitive comparision

Tags: c#, delegates

How to implement case insensitive comparison?

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person("P005", "Janson"));
persons.Add(new Person("P002", "Arnold"));
persons.Add(new Person("P007", "Kazhal"));
persons.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
persons.Sort((p1, p2) => string.Compare(p1.Name, p2.Name, true));
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean for Strings? In that case you can [the overload of the Compare-Funciton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y.aspx) which accepts a third parameter, a boolean which determines case-sesnsitivity:

```
String.Compare(
    string1,   // String 1
    string2,   // String 2
    true       // IgnoreCase
);
```

Or, if you want to, but I don't see why, you can go the very dirty way...

```
string1.ToLower() == string2.ToLower()
```

On the other side, if you are *very srious* about comparing those strings, you can use this:

```
string1.ToUpper() == string2.ToUpper()
```

Comment: The dirty way will fail if there's even one null value for string1 or string2 in the entire collection

Comment: @Russell Steen: null-safety was not a requirement. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
"abc".Equals("ABC", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `new CaseInsensitiveComparer().CompareTo(str1, str2)`

Answer (score 1):

You could just call

```
p1.Name.ToLower().CompareTo(p2.Name.ToLower())
```

for a quick implementation. Probably not the best long term solution though.